# Проблемы в верстке меню

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка

Всем привет! Ребятушки, такой вопрос. Есть код:

```css
   

 .window .menu ul li a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.813em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold; }


.page {
  max-width: 1600px;
  background: url("images/bg.png");
  min-height: 800px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto; }


.window {
  max-width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
  
  .window .menu ul {
    text-align: center; }
  
  .window .menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 67px; }
    
 
  .window .menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="window">
            <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="logo"><img src="styles/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
</div
```

Макет [image: Как должно быть]

У меня возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Никак не получается повлиять на отступы логотипа. Стараюсь присвоить ему класс, но все равно не сдвигается никак из общего списка. Подскажите как это сделать, либо есть дургой способ, чтобы ссылки были на уровне середины лого как на макете?
2. Смотрите, я назначил margin-top, но при этом, отступ у ссылок от верхнего края, раза в два больше, чем назначено. с чем связано такое назначение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
  max-width: 1600px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 800px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.window {
  max-width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(1),
.menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 1;
}

.menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
  order: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(1),
  .menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(4),
  .menu>ul>li:nth-of-type(5) {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="window">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.window .menu ul li a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.813em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.window .menu ul li a.logo {
  width:70px;
}
.window .menu ul li a.logo img {
  width:100%;
}

.page {
  max-width: 1600px;
  background: url("images/bg.png");
  min-height: 800px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.window {
  max-width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.window .menu ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.window .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.window .menu ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.window .menu ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="window">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="http://www.logologo.com/logos/g-logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

По поводу логотипа вы всегда можете использовать `position: absolute` для его точного позиционирования все зависимости от контейнера. Иначе для смещения логотипа примените к классу `logo`:

```
display: block;
```

По поводу верхнего отступа. Причина в отступах элемента UL. Вы не сделали Reset стиля для этого элемента, браузер делает отступы на свое усмотрение. Сделайте:

```
ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```